# Secret Santa Application : Practical Interview Test

Tags: javascript, interview-questions, promise, backbone.js, marionette.js

I was given a practical task as part of an interview for a front-end developer position. There is a follow up interview and I'm looking for some constructive criticism / tough love to help me prepare.

The guidelines were:

- Should work on IE8
- Use CDN's for external libraries
- Use whichever library(ies) you prefer
- Should take 2 hours

The code below is condensed into one file for convenience. There is a working version at http://54.201.30.172/frontend-challenge/

```
<div id="app">
  <!-- Generated Secret Santa assignments should go here -->
  <div id='participant-list'>

  </div>
</div>


<script type="text/template" id="rootTemplate">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  </tbody>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="preventDups" name="preventDups" <% if(preventDuplicates){ %> checked <% } %> />No Buy Backs
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>


      <td></td>
      <td>
        <button class="shuffleButton">Reshuffle</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>

</script>

<script type="text/template" id="oneParticipantTpl">

  <td> <%= name.first %> <%= name.last %> </td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td> buys for </td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <% if(buysFor){ %>
    <td id="<%= buysFor.guid %>"> <%= buysFor.name.first %> <%= buysFor.name.last %> </td>
  <% } %>

</script>


<script type="text/javascript">


  (function(){  

    var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

      idAttribute : 'guid',

      defaults:{
        "name": {
          "first": "",
          "last": ""
        },
        "email": "",
        "phone": "",
        "buysFor": null
      },

      initialize: function(){

        // The user cannot buy for themselves
        // Store their own id in an array of ids they can't buy for
        // Any additional users that they can't buy for will be added here too
        this.set('cantBuyFor', [this.get('guid')]);

        // Set the display name for convenience
        this.set('displayName', this.get('name').first + ' ' + this.get('name').last)
      }

    });

    var UsersCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

      model : UserModel,
      url : 'users.json',

      // Parse the users property from the ajax request
      parse: function(resp){
        return resp.users;
      }

    });

    var OneParticipantView = Mn.ItemView.extend({

      // Childview of All particiapnts view
      // Renders each row in the table
      template: '#oneParticipantTpl',
        tagName: 'tr'

    });

    var AllParticipantsViewModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

      // model to render and control whether recipients can buy for their buyers (buy backs)
      defaults : {
        preventDuplicates: true
      }
    });

    var AllParticipantsView = Mn.CompositeView.extend({

      template : '#rootTemplate',
      childView : OneParticipantView, 
      childViewContainer: 'tbody',
      tagName: 'table',
      model : new AllParticipantsViewModel(),

      // Make sure that we render the table when the collection is updated from the server
      collectionEvents: {
          'sync': 'reShuffle'
      },

      ui: {
        shuffleButton: '.shuffleButton',
        dupsCheckbox : '.preventDups'
      },

      events: {
        'click @ui.shuffleButton': 'reShuffle',
        'click @ui.dupsCheckbox' : 'changeDups'
      },

      changeDups: function(e){

        // toggle whether buy backs are enabled
        // Set the view-model property to whatever the user has selected and rerender the list
        e.preventDefault();
        var $checkbox = $(e.currentTarget);

        if($checkbox.is(':checked')){
          this.model.set('preventDuplicates', true);
        }else{
          this.model.set('preventDuplicates', false);
        }

        return this.render();
      },

      initialize : function(){
        // This can be used if the models are bootstrapped into the page rather than loaded over ajax
        //this.shuffle();
      },

      validRecipients: function(buyer, boughtFor){

        // Returns the list of people the buyer can buy for
        // This should be everyone less people who have already been bought for and anyone the buyer is forbidden to buy for (themselves)
        var validRecipients = this.collection.clone();
        validRecipients.remove(buyer.get('cantBuyFor'));
        validRecipients.remove(boughtFor);
        return validRecipients;
      },

      validSwaps: function(buyer){

        // Returns a list of people the buyer can swap without breaking rules
        var validSwaps = this.collection.clone();
        validSwaps.filter(function(recipient){
          return buyer.get('cantBuyFor').indexOf(recipient.get('guid')) === -1;
        });

        return validSwaps;
      },


      randomDraw: function(max){
        // Random number generator
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
      },

      preventDuplicatesDraw: function(buyer, recipient){

        // Prevent the recipient from buying back to the buyer if duplicates are disabled
        if(this.model.get('preventDuplicates')){
          recipient.get('cantBuyFor').splice(0,0, buyer.get('guid'));
        }else{
          return false;
        }
      },

      shuffle: function(){

        var boughtFor = [];

        this.collection.each(function(buyer, idx){

          // get all the valid recipients for this buyer as a backbone collection
          // NB. Valid recipients is not this.collection, it is a clone
          var validRecipients = this.validRecipients(buyer, boughtFor);

          if(validRecipients.length){

            // remove the recipient from the hat and match it to the actual human recipient
            var recipientTicket = validRecipients.at(this.randomDraw(validRecipients.length));
            var recipient = this.collection.get(recipientTicket.get('guid'));

            // give the recipient to the buyer
            buyer.set('buysFor', recipient.toJSON());

            this.preventDuplicatesDraw(buyer, recipient);

            // Set aside the recipients ticket
            boughtFor.push(recipient.get('guid'));  

          }else{

            this.makeSwap(buyer);       
          }

        }, this);

        return this.collection;

      },


      makeSwap : function(buyer){


        // Pick out a person to swap with at random (not the last)
        var validSwaps = this.validRecipients(buyer, []);

        var randomSwapper = this.collection.at(this.randomDraw(validSwaps.length));

        // Temporarily leave one person to buy for themselves
        buyer.set('buysFor', randomSwapper.get('buysFor'));

        // Swap with someone
        randomSwapper.set('buysFor', buyer.toJSON());
      },



      reShuffle: function(){
        // Shuffle reassign the pairs and reset the collection
        // Resetting the collection will rerender the list
        var reShuffled = this.shuffle();
        this.collection.reset(reShuffled.toJSON());
      }

    });


    var RootView = Mn.LayoutView.extend({

      el: '#app',

      regions : {
        "participantList": "#participant-list"
      },

      initialize: function() {
        // pass the collection down to the composite view
        this.getRegion('participantList').show(new AllParticipantsView({
          collection : this.collection
        }));
      }
    });



    var usersColl = new UsersCollection();

    var app = new Mn.Application({
        container : 'body',
        rootView :  new RootView({collection:usersColl})
    });

    usersColl.fetch().then(function(){
        app.start();
    });

    })();


</script>
```

Comment: At this moment I personally do not consider this a good question. Please see [this checklist for how to write a good Code Review question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/6429/31562) for how you can improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was evaluating this code as a sample for an interview, I might be deterred by the inconsistent indentation - some blocks are indented with two spaces while others have four spaces. I do like the usage of templates and promises.

One suggestion I have would be to consider eliminating the extra lambda function when starting the application:

> ```
> usersColl.fetch().then(function(){
>     app.start();
> });
> ```

And use a reference to the start method as the promise callback:

```
usersColl.fetch().then(app.start);
```

This may complicate matters because the method would receive as arguments any parameters returned from the promise. If that becomes an issue, maybe a [partially bound function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partially_applied_functions) would help.